# Fatal error- Monodevelop-Unity failed to start

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I originally installed unity but the monodevelop seems to not been installed as i tried to open a script in unity but nothing come out, saying i should find a software that opens it up when i have already set the preferences to monodevelop(built-in).

Then i reinstalled it again, this time, it contains visual studio too. then it can only open with visual studio. When I tried to open with monodevelop, the following pop-up will apear.

[image: pop-up error]

But I have already installed the two things which is /net and gtk. as shown below. what is the problem?

[image: software instaled]

Comment: When did you install Gtk and how did you install it? Before Unity or after Unity...Where did you install it? For Monodevelop, did you install it from Unity or from some random place on the internet?

Comment: 1st time-- install gtk after install unity(no monodev)
2nd time-- install monodevelop with unity

i went to the monodev website and it says xamarin studio not monodevelop

Comment: The first time is where you messed up. Look at my answer

Comment: check tis out buddy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336835 @Programmer

Answer (score 1):

> 1st time-- install gtk after install unity(no monodev) 2nd time--
>   install monodevelop with unity i went to the monodev website and it
>   says xamarin studio not monodevelop

You messed up in the first step.

You have to Uninstall **gtk** and everything else you installed during this time. This includes Unity too.If possible, do a system restore and set the restore date to the time before you installed any of this.

Now, install Unity, make sure that `MonoDevelop` is selected from Unity and then install it. Don't install **gtk** or any other software. When using Unity, `MonoDevelop` must be installed from Unity and not from any other website. The reason for this is because they are using a customized version of `MonoDevelop`.

Comment: can i just uninstall all the unity, gtk, microsoft net, and others? then reinstall again?? coz i have several files that i don wan to lose. and I don remember when is the time for the installation

Comment: @user3411128 You don't lose personal files when you perform system restore and choose a restore point. You will only loose installed programs within that time. Your personal files will be there. It only affects installed programs, drivers and system settings. Go ahead and try to uninstall them one by one. If that doesn't work, then system restore is your last option. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Mayb because i installed the unity directly without uninstall the previous one so it has the error. I restored the system to when I finished installed unity for the first time and uninstall it. Then reinstalled it and it has no problem now.  But my storage space does not reduce after i uninstall the first one. Y?

Comment: @user3411128 **Mayb because i installed the unity directly without uninstall the previous one so it has the error** I don't know what you mean by that. You installed Unity on top of another version of Unity without uninstalling the old one? **But my storage space does not reduce after i uninstall the first one.** Sometimes, restart is required for hardrive to update the size. If your problem is solved, don't forget to accept this answer.